# How to actually deploy a live blockchain?

Tags: development, blockchains

I have been researching a lot about how to build a new blockchains. So far, all guides say very similar things:

- Identify use case
- Identify consensus method
- Design nodes
- design blockchain
- select a blockchain platform
- do it

But I am looking for more detailed information, like what do I actually need if I want to deploy a live blockchain. Let's say I choose EOSIO, or openchain, whatever blockchain platform. But then what do I actually need to do in order to deploy it once it's developed so that people can start using it? How do I make it go live? How do I deploy it into that network? Do I need a public server running a node? Can I run a node just from my computer? Since everything we hear is that it's "descentralized" it wouldn't make too much sense that one would need a server so that people can join, right? What data does the node need to share so that others can join the blockchain?

Also what if i don't choose any of those platforms like openchain, eosio, ethereum, etc. Let's say i want to build a new blockchain in a new network from scratch, like bitcoin or ethereum. What would the requirements be? Does it cost any money?

These are the kind of things I want to know but can't seem to find anywhere.

If there is any blockchain developing expert with some spare time, I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up different things.  Since this is is the EOSIO stack exchange, I will answer for EOSIO:

If you want to deploy an entirely new blockchain using eosio software, then you need to setup server infrastructure to host it.

If you want to deploy a contract to an existing blockchain (such as EOS Mainnet, which is using the eosio software) then you can use the publicly available nodes to deploy your contract. You can also deploy your own node (running the eosio software) and connect it to the EOS Mainnet.